# Getting json data from snowflake to python

Tags: python, json, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am able to get the data, but not in the format I want.

When ran in python as:
[the query in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA6yR.png)
I get:
[the output in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o01TL.png)

How can I get it to be in this format?: (which is the format I get when running the query in snowflake):
[the output in snowflake 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mesx.png)
[the output in snowflake 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZO9E.png)
I ultimately want to write the formatted result into a .json file. Currently, when I write into a json file I get the same wrong format above.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include any relevant information (code, output) [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability to others as they cannot be searched.

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct, the "\n" are interpreted as line breaks:
`

```
>>> result = '''[('{\n "extras": [\n "ext warranty", \n "paint protection" \n ], \n "make": "Honda", \n "model": "Civic", \n "price": "20275", \n "year": "2017"\n}',), ('{\n "extras" : [\n "ext warranty", \n "rust proofing", \n "fabric protection" \n ], \n "make": "Toyota", \n "model": "Camry", \n "price": "23500", \n "year": "2017" \n}',)]'''
>>> result
'[(\'{\n "extras": [\n "ext warranty", \n "paint protection" \n ], \n "make": "Honda", \n "model": "Civic", \n "price": "20275", \n "year": "2017"\n}\',), (\'{\n "extras" : [\n "ext warranty", \n "rust proofing", \n "fabric protection" \n ], \n "make": "Toyota", \n "model": "Camry", \n "price": "23500", \n "year": "2017" \n}\',)]'
>>> print(result)
[('{
 "extras": [
 "ext warranty", 
 "paint protection" 
 ], 
 "make": "Honda", 
 "model": "Civic", 
 "price": "20275", 
 "year": "2017"
}',), ('{
 "extras" : [
 "ext warranty", 
 "rust proofing", 
 "fabric protection" 
 ], 
 "make": "Toyota", 
 "model": "Camry", 
 "price": "23500", 
 "year": "2017" 
}',)]
```

`

You may want to format the string because the json objects should not be encased in single quotation marks and the line results from the query should not be encased in parenthesis:

`

```
>>> parsed_result = result.replace("'","").replace("(","").replace(",)","")
>>> print(parsed_result)
[{
 "extras": [
 "ext warranty", 
 "paint protection" 
 ], 
 "make": "Honda", 
 "model": "Civic", 
 "price": "20275", 
 "year": "2017"
}, {
 "extras" : [
 "ext warranty", 
 "rust proofing", 
 "fabric protection" 
 ], 
 "make": "Toyota", 
 "model": "Camry", 
 "price": "23500", 
 "year": "2017" 
}]
```

`

You can also check that this is a valid json string by converting it to a dictionary using python built-in json library:
`

```
>>> import json
>>> dict_result = json.loads(parsed_result)
>>> dict_result
[{'extras': ['ext warranty', 'paint protection'], 'make': 'Honda', 'model': 'Civic', 'price': '20275', 'year': '2017'}, {'extras': ['ext warranty', 'rust proofing', 'fabric protection'], 'make': 'Toyota', 'model': 'Camry', 'price': '23500', 'year': '2017'}]
```

`